# Variável dinâmica no angularJS

Tags: angularjs

Quero gerar uma variável dinamicamente no angularJS sendo um ng-repeat dentro do outro conforme abaixo:

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in vm.data.data track by $index">
  <td class="center" ng-repeat="field in vm.data.field">         
    {{data + '.' + field}}
  </td>
</tr>
```

e está imprimindo:

> [object Object].name
>
> [object Object].value

sendo que `data` é um array de objetos:

```
vm.data.data = [{name: 'Teste 1', value: 5311},{ name: 'Teste 2', value: 5245},{ name: 'Teste 3', value: 5236} ,{ name: 'Teste 4', value: 5243}]};
```

e

```
// São os campos da tabela, pois eles são dinâmicos
vm.data.field = ['name', 'value'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Resolvido:

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in vm.data.data track by $index">
  <td class="center" ng-repeat="field in vm.data.field track by $index">
    {{data[field]}}
  </td>
</tr>
```